# Remove date in Datetime from SQL Server GETDATE() Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I'm making a query that fetches the records for the current date regardless of the time, how can I make it on SQL Server? My version of SQL Server doesn't support **DATE** for conversion. I want a format like:

```
2013-06-20
```

So for example my query is:

```
SELECT * FROM sometable where date = GETDATE();
```

Where `GETDATE()` is in a format **2015-06-19 19:12:10.953**.
I want it to be **2015-06-19** in the query.

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: how can your date have that format when you can't use date conversion, you will be unable to use date as datatype. Is your column date declared as a char(10) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 120)` will make the date to ISO format, then SUBSTRING will get only date part:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sometable 
WHERE date = SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 120), 1, 10)
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. I only need the date with the format i mentioned and works perfectly. thanks

Comment: This answer does an unnecessary conversion of a date to a character string.  It is much better to simply use `cast(getdate() as date)` to remove the time component.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Comment: @gordonLinoff You are correct but `date` type does not exist in all SQL Server versions.

Answer (score 4):

You *could* express the query as:

```
SELECT *
FROM sometable 
WHERE date = cast(GETDATE() as date);
```

However, an alternative way to phrase this is:

```
SELECT *
FROM sometable 
WHERE date >= cast(GETDATE() as date) and
      date < cast(dateadd(day, 1, GETDATE()) as date)
```

This version is more guaranteed to use an appropriate index, if available.

Comment: I would add that the first query will only produce results if the date column is of type date or it's time part is midnight.

Comment: Thanks. I wish I clould select this answer as well, I can use this technique in the future for I am also making a from date and to date queries. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try following

```
SELECT * FROM sometable where DATEDIFF(DAY, date,GETDATE())=0;
```

Thanks

Comment: although this will give the correct result. This solution will not perform well. It will not allow indexes and be very slow when comparing

Answer (score 0):

You may try CAST : like this :

```
SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 

SELECT CAST(date AS DATE) FROM UserMaster where date = GETDATE();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your version of sqlserver does not support DATE conversion (you must be using sqlserver 2005 or older), you need to recalculate getdate().

```
SELECT *
FROM
  sometable
WHERE
  date >= dateadd(d, datediff(d,0, GETDATE()), 0)
  and date < dateadd(d, datediff(d,0, GETDATE()), 1)
```

If your date is declared as a char(10) or similar, you can simply use this where clause:

```
WHERE date = convert(char(10), GETDATE(), 126)
```

This is the interval that will be included. Excluding todate:

```
SELECT 
  dateadd(d, datediff(d,0, GETDATE()), 0) fromdate,
  dateadd(d, datediff(d,0, GETDATE()), 1) todate
```

Result:

```
fromdate                  todate
2015-06-19 00:00:00.000   2015-06-20 00:00:00.000
```